# OAuth2 Resource/Authentication server for Play2 Java

Tags: oauth, playframework, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.0

Is there any implementation of OAuth2 Resource / Authentication server for Play2 Java?

SO far I have only encountered OAuth2 Resource / Authentication server for Play2 Scala.